# Using react-hot-loader 3 with own server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I was able to set up `react-hot-loader` to work properly bundling my client js and pushing changes to browser and applying there (except `[react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored` warning).
I'm using my own server with `koa`, `koa-webpack-dev-middleware` and `koa-webpack-hot-middleware`, that processes webpack and hot. It also handles server rendering of my app with this code

```
export default function *renderReact() {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  const store   = makeStore(history);

  const [redirectLocation, renderProps] = yield match.bind(null, { routes, location: this.url, history });

  if (redirectLocation) {
    return this.redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
  }

  if (renderProps == null) {
    return this.throw(404, 'Not found')
  }

  const rootElement = (
    <Provider store={store} key="provider">
      <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
    </Provider>
  );

  this.body = renderApp({
    html:  yield store.renderToString(ReactDOMServer, rootElement),
    state: JSON.stringify(store.getState())
  });
}
```

The problem is with my server side code: `hot` works only for client code and updates changes on the fly, but my server code does not get updated on changes as scripts a loaded on server start and on page reload i get not updated rendered page from server and then it updates with new client code.
and react warning `Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid...`
The question is: how to handle code changes related to server rendering part on server not restarting the app as it breaks hot loading?